# Jquery Elements draggable into time slots

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to build elements that can be dragged on time slots in javascript, jquery or any other technology.

Example: I have various activities to be entrusted to workers with different time frames (30 minutes, 50 minutes, 70 minutes, etc.)

Below I have a list of users/workers who have free time zones throughout the day

I should create a grid where for example the user James who does his daily job from 9am to 6pm has a time slot divided into 15 minute squares. The program should allow me to drag the activity slots to assign to James only if he has a free time frame to carry out that activity.

Is there anything like this? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the Tour and provide a [mcve].